# Htaccess 404 redirect custom rule for nested directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I have a site with custom .htaccess file that handles few things:

1) It treats urls without ".php" extensions as if it has ".php" in the end.

2) It redirects http:// and http://www. urls to https://www.

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine On

## add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# if not a directory and .php file is present then add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Everything works as expected, but I discovered some weird uls in Webmaster Tools that result in 500 error instead of 404:

When you visit non-existed root level url such as https://www.example.com/skjdfhkj it redirects to 404 as expected.

However, when you visit some nested url such as https://www.example.com/some-page/skjdfhkj , where `some-page` matches the name of existing php file, then it gives out a 500 Server Error. When `some-page` does not match any existing php files, then it returns 404 as expected.

All the ulrs in this site are root level and there are no nested folder structures anywhere. I have checked the code and there are no links pointing to the nested urls, so not sure how they got to Webmasters Tools, most likely there were some erroneous links at some point on the site which are no longer there.

My question is, how do I update my htaccess to properly return a 404 when someone visits non-existing nested url such as https://www.example.com/some-page/skjdfhkj ?

Comment: Try adding `Options -MultiViews` at top of your .htaccess

Comment: @anubhava I tried and got the same result. One thing I've just noticed (and updated in my question), is when you visit some nested url such as https://www.example.com/some-page/skjdfhkj , where `some-page` matches the name of existing php file, then it gives out a 500 Server Error. When `some-page` does not match any existing php files, then it returns 404 as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All the ulrs in this site are root level and there are no nested folder structure anywhere.

You can use this code block to replace all of your .htaccess code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Options -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On

## add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# if not a directory and .php file is present then add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: now I am facing the situation where I need to introduce some nested url structure on the site but it wouldn't work properly. I have posted this question as a separate question here too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59364084/ , maybe you can take a look?