# 500 Server error instead of 404 on nested urls due to mod rewrite htaccess rule(s)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I have a site with custom .htaccess file that handles few things:

1) It treats urls without ".php" extensions as if it has ".php" in the end.

2) It redirects `http://` and `http://www.` urls to `https://www.`

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Options -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On

## add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# if not a directory and .php file is present then add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Everything works as expected, but I have observed some strange behavior that resulted in 500 errors instead of 404:

1) When you visit non-existed root level url such as https://www.example.com/skjdfhkj it redirects to `404` as expected.

2) When you visit non-existed nested url such as https://www.example.com/some-text/skjdfhkj where `some-text` does not match any existing php files, then it returns `404` as expected.

3) However, when you visit some non-existed nested url such as https://www.example.com/some-existing-page-name/skjdfhkj , where `some-existing-page-name` matches the name of existing php file (https://www.example.com/some-existing-page-name.php), then it gives out a `500 Server Error`.

My question is: how do I update my htaccess to properly return a `404` instead of `500` when someone visits non-existing nested url such as https://www.example.com/some-existing-page-name/skjdfhkj (where `some-existing-page-name` matches the name of existing php file (https://www.example.com/some-existing-page-name.php)) ?

I guess it has something to do with mod rewrite that treats urls without `.php` extensions as if it had `.php`, but don't know how to modify htaccess to make it work properly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing last rule as this:

```
# if not a directory and .php file is present then add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

`%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` sometimes can give unexpected matches from filesystem using partial matches.

Comment: Thank you love, god bless your soul!